# Who gets the tax credit, if I say yes to "Would you like to donate a dollar to xyz" at the cashier of a shop in the U.S.A.?

Tags: united-states, tax-law

I often get asked by some fast food restaurants and other businesses to make a donation to  such and such cause when I try to pay at the cashier.

If I say yes, who gets the tax credit?

Me or the business?

Comment: You can only claim the deduction if you are donating to a 501(c)(3) organization. If somebody puts out a bucket that says "help Becky buy a car for her kids", that is a gift, not a donation. Be sure you know the difference before you try to claim it. Be careful with these donations, for example "Firehouse Subs" claims to be all about the firemen, but only donate 0.11% of sales to its own foundation which then helps people (but incurs costs). You're usually better off donating directly.

Answer (score 3):

First, there's no tax credit (at least on the Federal side), just a tax deduction (and even that isn't guaranteed - depends on your personal circumstances).

Second, you get to claim the deduction (you should keep your receipt, just in case).